# Parallel execution speed of a vectorized function using numba

Tags: numpy, numba

Years ago I wrote a math library with `numba` to do vectorized operations on large arrays of elements (example: multiply two array of matrices). I recently opened it up to experiment with parallelism (feature which did not exist at the time). In doing so there was a speed improvement but not as much as I expected.

To further understand, I wrote this basic example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange, float64

@njit(float64[:] (float64[:], float64[:]), parallel=True)
def array_sum(array0, array1):
    """
    Sum elements of array0 to array1, similar to doing + on two numpy arrays
    """

    result = np.empty(array0.shape)

    for i in prange(array0.shape[0]):
        result[i] = array0[i] + array1[i]

    return result
```

And then tested with:

```
import time
v0 = np.random.random(10**7) # 10 million floats
v1 = np.random.random(10**7) # 10 million floats
array_sum(v0,v1) # run this once so the code compiles

#--- test start ---#
start_time = time.time()
array_sum(v0,v1) # do the work
end_time = time.time()
delta = end_time-start_time
print (delta)
```

On my machine I get the following results:

```
# direct numpy array0+array1 ---> 0.016865015029907227
# parallel=False             ---> 0.016468048095703125
# parallel=True              ---> 0.010709047317504883
```

With `parallel=False` the speed I get matches `numpy`'s, which is what I expected. And with `parallel=True` I got a ~1.54x speed increase, which is nice, but for a simple operation like this I was expecting a larger impact on my 8 core machine.

**QUESTION**

Can parallelism be used in a more effective way to do vectorized operations similar to the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`prange` does use multiple threads** if `parallel=True` is used, and so multiple cores (if available) of the target machine.

That being said, your computation is **memory bound**. For large arrays, array need to be read/written from/to the RAM which is a shared resource. Thus, **few cores are generally enough to saturate the RAM** (and this is likely not gonna be better in the future since the situation is getting worse for the last 3 decades). This is especially true on PC. On servers, this is a bit more complex often due to **NUMA** architecture.

The only way to improve the scalability is to make the code less-memory bound. For example, you can operate on **chunks** in the L1/L2 **cache** rather than in RAM (ie. better memory locality). But this requires to compute more than a sum of two arrays. Actually, this is useful when you want to merge few basic operations in one. Also note that in-place sums can be faster on most architectures (typically the ones with a write-allocate cache policy like x86-64).

Comment: This is especially true for such a simple operation as `+`. The size of array needed to see a multicore speedup should be rather large.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html correctly, the parallel option does not exploit your multiple cores: it mostly seems to generate SIMD (AVX, what-have-you) instructions. And in that case your operation is not likely to be sped up too far since it's bandwidth bound, so there is not much to be gained.